# Android button onclick method isn't working

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have the following piece of code
**Xml**:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/mainTextView"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="@string/hello_msg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button 
        android:id="@+id/submitButton"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Click"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:onClick="submit()"/>
```

**Java:**

```
public void submit(View view){
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mainTextView);
        tv1.setText("Clicked");
    }
```

Every time I tap the button my app crashes. How to fix it now?

Comment: Can you please share crash report here?

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting compile time error

`onClick handler method name cannot contain the character '('` in line `android:onClick="submit()"`.

And you might be getting you UI not visible as  `setContentView(R.layout.main)` inside button click callback.

```
public void submit(View view){
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mainTextView);
        tv1.setText("Clicked");
    }
```

You must set this in  a proper Activity lifecycle method viz in `OnCreateView()`.Something like this :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
```

***Happy Coding***

Answer (score 0):

The `onClick` Attribute can't parse the values which contains special characters. You have used the '(' and ')'. which is valid java. It cannot be used in XML Attributes.

write only clear name in xml attritube like,

```
...
android:onClick="submit"
...
```

And then create a method inside the `MainActivity.java`. you can press ALT+ENTER on the method name in XML attribute`"submit"`, which will create  method for you.

if this is not working then confirm that your button is initialized. App crash happens because of unintialized components too.

Or you can use `setOnClickListener` method in java file .

```
...
Button btn; // This variable can be global or local as per your need

btn = findViewById(R.id.submitButton);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Button","CLicked..");
            }
        });

...
```

Answer (score 0):

First, move your `setContentView` inside the `onCreate`:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
```

Second, write your submit method inside the class:

```
public void submit(View view) {
        TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mainTextView);
        tv1.setText("Clicked");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code ,

```
<Button 
        android:id="@+id/submitButton"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Click"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:onClick="submit()"/>
```

you can see a red line under **submit()**, if you keep mouse on it, you can see the description :

`onClick handler method name cannot contain the character '('`

after removing them, maybe again see a **warning message**:

```
Use databinding or explicit wiring of click listener in code
```

you have 3 options, first  `tools:ignore="UsingOnClickInXml"` or use `setOnClickListener` in your activity and the last one `data binding`

```
<data>
    <variable
      name="listener"
      type="android.view.View.OnClickListener" />
</data>
```